# Margin on every element except last

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, margins

I have 2 lines of CSS for setting margin on every element except the last one. Is there a way to combine it into 1 line?

This is what I have currently(working):

```
.work img {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.work img:last {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

I tried changing it to:

```
.work img:not(:last) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

But it is not working? Any idea why?

**UPDATE** I have only five images. My other option would be to only have margins on the first four.

Comment: You may want to try .work img:last-child { margin-right: 0px }

Comment: @Quintile that is still using 2 lines of CSS. I was just wondering if I could do it in one line. The first part of my code is working. Not the second part

Comment: The reason why is that there is no `:last` selector but we do have `:last-child` and `:last-of-type`.  I was playing around with these selectors and thought it might help someone in the future:  https://jsfiddle.net/21rs5dog/

Comment: @DylanValade https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/ and :last works fine when you test it by itself like `img:last`

Comment: You're right, :last is a jQuery selector but your question was about CSS and CSS does not support it currently.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You have small mistake

Change:

```
.work img:not(:last)
```

to

```
.work:not(:last-child)
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/deddnbrh/5/)

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
.work img {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.work img:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

or

```
.work img:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

or jQuery solution :

```
jQuery('.work img:not(:last)').css({marginRight: 10);
```

Remember, your browser need to have support for selector if you apply pure CSS.

See this for reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Alast-child

Answer (score 3):

If you need full browser support, I would suggest using some javascript, or adding a class of .last on the last img.  Otherwise you could just do:

```
.work img:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```